# find tag name on next commit with specific pattern after specific tag

Tags: git, unix

I want to find tag name on next commit with specific pattern after specific tag.
I used command

```
git describe --match 'alex-[0-9]{4}w[0-9]{2}.(A | B)' --abbrev=0 tag_name
```

but match doesn't work.
How can I match it ?

Comment: Example of tags that should match and did not?

Answer (score 1):

The `--match`operation takes [glob patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), not regular expressions.

Fortunately, in this particular case, what you've written as a regular expression is also expressible as a glob pattern.  (This is not true for other cases.)  Instead of:

```
[0-9]{4}
```

(which matches exactly 4 occurrences of those characters), use:

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

Repeat this for the `{2}` variant, with a different number.  Since `.` in a regular expression matches any non-newline character, replace it with `?`—or in this case, I suspect you meant a literal period anyway, in which case, just use `.`.  Finally, `(A|B)` in extended REs (the original should not have contained spaces) is equivalent to `[AB]` which has the same form in both kinds of patterns.

Hence, assuming I'm right that you wanted `\.` rather than just `.` in the original:

```
--match 'alex-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]w[0-9][0-9].[AB]'
```

Comment: if [AB} is A or B then how can I write Tue or Mon ? @torek

Comment: @Alex: you can't. That's (one example of) why not all regular expressions can be expressed as glob patterns. Fortunately `--match` allows you to repeat it, so you could write `--match 'foo-[0-9][ABC]-Mon' --match 'foo[0-9][ABC]-Tue'`, for instance, to glob-match the same strings as the extended RE `foo[0-9][ABC]-(Mon|Tue)`.